# How to force user to enter first letter Lowercase in EditText in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, popupwindow, lowercase

I was trying to find the answer here in stack overflow, but unable to find the right answer.

I am using a popup window for entering a license key. But the first letter while the keyboard popped up is by default uppercase.

I want lowercase to start typing.

Please, guys I want to mention, I already know there are other question like this, but none solved the problem of mine. And another thing to note, I only want to chnage my xml code, not in java class. So, if you want to mark this question as duplicate, first read the full description.

Thanks guys...

Comment: Did you try to use inputfilter class ?

Comment: all characters in lower case? Or just the first character?

Comment: only the first character

Comment: try this android:inputType="text|textEmailAddress"

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but using text email address is not the right way to do such a small task

Answer (score 1):

if you want to do this in xml then just add

> **android:inputType="textEmailAddress"** . in your edit text

and for programatically

**`myEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS);`**

Comment: I can solve the problem, but it includes '@' in the keyboard and also it is not the right way to do it, I believe....but thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
android:capitalize="none"
```

it force the fist letter lowercase
then, if you want uppercase, you must click the uppercase button

Comment: Not working, sorry

Answer (score -1):

**try this**

```
EditText text = new EditText(context);
text.setInputType(android.text.InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | android.text.InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
```

Comment: I want only xml code change, please find the "Edit"